# Elasticsearch inner query support

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do inner query on Elasticsearch  similar to an example on solr wiki

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible if your documents share same IDs. The technique is called application side joins (application because you/your app decide the IDs and not the ES engine).

An example of this would be: you have 2 indexes Students and Courses; and you want all the Courses documents where students containing the name "Jeff" are enrolled. Let's asume in your Student index, you have a field called courses, where the ids of the courses where that student is enrolled are stored.

In this case, if you want to use "aplication side joins", you would first query the Student index, taking the ids of the courses and checking that the name "Jeff" is present on the name field. After that, you do a 2nd query towards the Courses index, asking for those documents whose ids match the ones you received from your 1st query. This is the closest to a "join" you can get with the elastic search.

Often (in search models/ and search related technologies like ES), it is better do use another technique for the kind of "join-like" behavoiur you want, and this is called "index denormalization/ or data denormalization", and that is basically repeating (part/all) of an index information in another index. In the case of this example, this would mean repeating part of your courses information within the student index (so that you won't have to issue a 2nd query).

Even though data denormalization incur in higher usage of data, it diminishes search time bc you avoid issuing 2(or more) queries; as just 1 query, gives you all your joined data. If you use a normal relational normalized DB for storing your cannonical data representation and use the ES only as a search model for some critical queries, I'd highly suggest to you to denormalize and repeat the critical data in only index to avoid this type of application side joins.

In some specific cases though is better to separate indexes (and use app side joins instead of the denormalization approach). One such case is if your joined data receives frequent updates, because if you denormalized the data on another index; then you'll have to update the data across all instances of your index, which is not acceptable.

Hepe it helps.